# How do I find the closest action attribute to a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I am using the following code to extract the action from an html form:

```
var path = button.parent().parent().attr("action");
```

It works, but `.parent().parent()` is very fragile. what if I insert a new tag in between this and the form? It will break the functionality of my code. What would a safer alternative to this be?

Comment: do you have kind of container wrapped around it ?

Comment: Do you know the ID of the form? You could just use that.

Comment: Try `parents` or `closest`

Comment: also have prev() or prevAll()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var path = button.closest('[action]').attr("action");
```

This will find the closest ancestor(or itself) with an action attribute

Answer (score 1):

The only element in HTML that can have an action attribute is a form. In HTML a form cannot contain another form. Therefore, you want to find the form that is an ancestor of the button.

jQuery has a method for finding ancestor elements called `parents` (I have no idea why it isn't called `ancestors`). This takes a selector so you can filter it.

```
button.parents('form').attr('action')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `form` property of `HTMLButtonElement` object:

```
// property
var path = button.prop('form').action;
// attribute
var path = button.prop('form').getAttribute('action');
```